# Ruby On Rails Function Testing :index with a polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, case, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic model called Address, I am trying to currently write some basic function tests for this model and controller. For the controller I am at a loss on how to go about this. For example I have another model called Patient, each Patient will have an address, so i have started writing the following function test, but i have no idea how to use "get" with a nested polymorphic resource. Now I was able to find some polymorphic test information on Fixtures here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html
but this will not help me test against the index. Any help is much appreciated im at a total and complete loss here.

FILE: test/functional/addresses_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class AddressesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @address = addresses(:of_patient)
    @patient = patients(:one)
    activate_authlogic
  end

  test "patient addresses index without user" do
    get :index  <<<<<<<<<<<< what goes here????
    assert_redirected_to :login
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your controller is setup the way I think it might be:

```
def index
  if @current_user
    @addresses = @current_user.addresses.all
  else
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Then the test will probably look like this:

```
test "patient addresses index without user" do
  get :index, :patient_id => @patient.id
  assert_redirected_to :login
end

test "patient addresses with user" do
  @current_user = @patient
  get :index, :patient_id => @patient.id
  assert_response :success
end
```

The thing to keep in mind is that the index method needs the patient_id to process.

Comment: Wow thank you so much that worked perfectly! Do you know where i could find this in the docs? I searched high and low even asked a bit on IRC with no luck! So happy for this answer!